# What is the best application, that helps managing my own personal expenses?

Tags: android, web-apps, finance

I need a free application, that has both ONLINE and mobile (android) version to manage my expenses.

What would you recommend?

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Answer (score 2):

### You can try GnuCash for keeping track of your personal expenses

Open source [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) meets 3 of your 4 requirements:

- It helps you to manage your personal expenses.
- It is free.
- It has an Android companion application.

However please note that it is not online. It is a desktop application.

```
Full disclosure: I am the author of the Gnucash book.
```